# SQL Server Web Client?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, client, webclient

Is there any good working (& free) web client for SQL Server?

I mean something like "phpMyAdmin" for SQL Server...

I tried [MyLittleAdmin](http://mylittleadmin.com/) and some other weak projects. But I need a better interface with active development.

Comment: sql server express? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx